# Conversion from R data.table to nested list

Tags: r, performance, list, data.table

Supposed I'd like to create a nested list from an R data.table, as in the toy example below:

```
library(data.table)

generate_dt <- function(num_unique_id=100, rows_per_id=2) {
    num_rows <- num_unique_id * rows_per_id
    my_dt <- data.table(my_id=rep(seq(1, num_unique_id), rows_per_id),
                        y1=rnorm(num_rows), y2=rnorm(num_rows), y3=rnorm(num_rows),
                        z=runif(num_rows))
    setkey(my_dt, my_id)
    return(my_dt)
}

## Suppose I want to go from my_dt to a nested list
list_from_dt <- function(my_dt) {
    num_unique_id <- length(unique(my_dt$my_id))
    my_list <- lapply(seq_len(num_unique_id), function(id) {
        my_dt_subset <- my_dt[J(id)]
        return(list(y=as.matrix(my_dt_subset[, c("y1", "y2", "y3"), with=FALSE]),
                    max_z=max(my_dt_subset$z)))

    })
    stopifnot(is.matrix(my_list[[1]]$y))
    return(my_list)
}

my_dt <- generate_dt()
my_list <- list_from_dt(my_dt)  # Suppose I have some code that expects a nested list like this

system.time(replicate(100, unused <- generate_dt()))  # Fast, 0.062 elapsed
system.time(replicate(100, unused <- list_from_dt(my_dt)))  # Roughly 200 times slower (12.586 elapsed)
```

Why is creating the nested list so slow relative to creating the data table?  Is there a way to speed up my `list_from_dt` function?  I assume the lookups into `my_dt` are relatively fast since it is keyed by id.  Is the bottleneck coming from allocating lots of little fragmented pieces of memory for the matrices in my nested list?

Comment: I mean, it's not surprising that it is slow to split an obj up and compute summary stats, is it? Nor that it is fast to create a single object. You might be interested in `lapply(split(...))`. The `split.data.table` function is efficient and available on the devel version of the package (1.9.7).

Comment: @Frank thank you for that pointer, I'll try and get data.table 1.9.7 working (I have 1.9.6).  I'm not surprised that list_from_dt is slower, but I am surprised by how much slower.  It's not doing much computation, only copying data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I see with `split` and `gmax`:

```
f = function(){
    s  = lapply(split(my_dt[, !"z", with=FALSE], by="my_id", keep.by=FALSE), as.matrix)
    mz = my_dt[, max(z), by=my_id]
    Map(list, ys = s, mz = mz$V1)
}

system.time(replicate(100, generate_dt()))          #  0.1
system.time(replicate(100, list_from_dt(my_dt)))    # 20.1
system.time(replicate(100, f()))                    #  2.1
```

It looks like this:

```
> head(res, 2)
$`1`
$`1`$ys
              y1          y2          y3
[1,] -0.04493979 -1.01340856  0.08481358
[2,] -0.75860610  0.04113645 -0.36270441

$`1`$mz
[1] 0.9362695


$`2`
$`2`$ys
            y1         y2        y3
[1,] 0.7718361 -0.8005803 1.2195464
[2,] 0.1658420 -1.2846028 0.4607024

$`2`$mz
[1] 0.8551927
```

The numbers, `` `1` `` and `` `2` `` are the `my_id` values, now serving as names for list elements.